# dom objects load up scrampbled/out of place, then setup properly on full load

Tags: html, css, dom

Ive had a small problem that, although not frequent but it DOES happen to me and the problem is that,
when a page is loading, certain elements appear out of whack, out of place. Then when the whole thing is loaded, it goes where it should.

so for example, this latest wordpress site i just recently built for a client

http://www.islandlivingpatio.com/

when the page is first loading, the main image is off to the center/side. After full load all falls into place. At first i thought it was the slider i was using but then a friend just now asks me "why does my page do this (as described above) and i didnt have an answer.

http://discoverarmenia.org/tourism.php

notice how his content div loads to the side as well.

Im not sure how to address it. Its not a huge deal especially when the page loads fast but when on a slow connection its pretty apparent.

Any ideas as to how to correct this?

thanks in advanced.

Comment: Is your content inserted into HTML via Javascript/Ajax? if so you can populate your containers after the document has loaded, at `$document.ready()`

Answer (score 1):

I believe what is happening, is the content is getting loaded, and then styled. For example that tourism page, that div is floated left. So the all the content is loaded and then the styles.

Your Styles are also in the body not the head. Styles and Meta should live in the head!

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Probably is because your main image is set to `float:left(right);`, when it's first loaded, it will probably not on the desired position until other elements besides it is loaded and squeeze it to the proper position. hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you need to move your styles in header. For the tourism page this could be quick workaround:

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
```

to

```
<div id="slider" style="height:376px" class="nivoSlider">
```

This will put your content div in right spot. Users with slow connection won't notice any div moves after styles are loaded.